# How to add TIKA into build.gradle using android studio?

Tags: android, build.gradle, apache-tika

I'm trying to put Apache Tika into my project.
But it returns error, unfortunately, I couldn't solve this problem by myself.

How can I put Apache Tika using android studio?

> Error:(27, 0) Gradle DSL method not found: 'runtime()'
>       Possible causes:
>
> The project 'AudioTest' may be using a version of Gradle that does not contain the method.
>       Open Gradle wrapper file
>
> The build file may be missing a Gradle plugin.
>       Apply Gradle plugin

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.test.audiotest"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-appindexing:8.1.0'
    runtime 'org.apache.tika:tika-parsers:1.13'
}
```

this is my build.gradle module:app

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.2'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

this is my build.gradle project:AudioTest

Comment: Show your build.gradle file

Answer (score 3):

change

```
runtime 'org.apache.tika:tika-parsers:1.13'
```

to

```
compile 'org.apache.tika:tika-parsers:1.13'
```